# Constructor does not pass initial array values to the method

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods, constructor

I would like an explanation what I'm doing wrong. I paste two block of codes; one is working another is not working. The first code works becasue the initial values are passed into the method "MyGreatMethod" I can see them:

```
 public class Something
    {
        private int [] MyArray = new int [3];

        public Something()
        {
            MyArray[0] = 100;
            MyArray[1] = 200;
            MyArray[2] = 300;
        }

        public void MyGreatMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[0] / 3);
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[1] / 3);
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[2] / 3);
        }

    }
```

but if I place values into "MyArray" this way(see below), the method "MyGreatMethod" gets NULLs from constructor, what I do wrong? Please help..

```
public class Something
    {
        private int [] MyArray = new int [3];

        public Something()
        {
            int[] MyArray = {100,200,300};
        }

        public void MyGreatMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[0] / 3);
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[1] / 3);
            Console.WriteLine(MyArray[2] / 3);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is local variable. Try to remove int[]

Comment: That's because in the 2nd snippet you're initializing a *local variable* named `MyArray` instead of the *instance field* named `MyArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **new** keyword when you want to set values for a specific array after the declaration:

```
public class Something
{
    private int[] MyArray;

    public Something()
    {
        MyArray = new int[3] { 100, 200, 300 };
    }

    public void MyGreatMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[0] / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[1] / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[2] / 3);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you !That was that! This is now working! May ask when one should use "this"

Answer (score 3):

It is `null` because you haven't assigned the values to `MyArray`. Instead, you have created a *new* array and assigned it to a *local variable* with the same name.

You should remove the `int[]` from the constructor:

```
public class Something
{
    private int [] MyArray = new int [3];

    public Something()
    {
        MyArray = {100,200,300};
    }

    public void MyGreatMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[0] / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[1] / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(MyArray[2] / 3);
    }
}
```